# Check application running in sikuli

Tags: python, ui-automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

I'm working in sikuli-1.1.1,python. I need to automate a code to open a website. So, I have to open chrome and type the link in a tab with sikuli. As for now I'm using this code to open chrome,

```
 app = App("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
 app.open()
```

but I don't want to open a new instance(window) every time.How to check whether the application is already running or not?.

Comment: if (!app.isRunning())

Comment: Thanks, it worked. @dram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly - yes, you can do it like this (I only have Sikuli running in Java but that method should be available via the API):

```
print app.isRunning()
```

that should give you `true` or `false` response.

Having said that, you should consider adding some setup/cleanup functionality that will prepare a fresh environment before each test and clean it up after a test is finished. This will reduce the number of false positives and is the right thing to do.

Comment: It worked. isRunning() is available for sikuli ver-1.1+ it seems.
find more on:http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appclass.html